# Kendo template binding strange behavior

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI for my web application. I have such a strange (maybe) behavior in my application:

There are four output that appears on the console :

nb calls: 1

nb calls: 2

nb calls: 3

nb calls: 4

I do not understand why the getItems function is called 4 times during the binding?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='listview' data-bind="source: getItems" data-template="item-template"></div>

    <script id="item-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
      <span>
        <h2>${name}</h2>
      </span>
    </script>

    <script>
      var items = [
        { name: "Item 1" },
        { name: "Item 2" },
        { name: "Item 3" }
      ];    

      var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        calls:0,
        getItems: function() { 
          this.calls++;
          console.log("nb calls: " + this.calls);
          return items;
        },
      });
  
      kendo.bind(document.body, viewModel);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Could you help me to find what's the reason?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One would need to step through the kendo code to know (and I'm not motivated to do so hence this is not an answer...) but I imagine there is one call to get the length to construct a loop and then one call (applying an index to the result) per template iteration for the three items.

Comment: @NigelK Thanks for your help. There is all the same 4 calls even with only one or no items